# importar colors.py dentro de una carpeta python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

yo tengo esta estructura en mi programa

```
-- juego\
    |
    |-- core\
    |    |
    |    |--colors.py
    |
    |__main__.py
```

tengo que importar colors.py a mi archivo **main**.py

¿como se podría hacer?

Comment: Considera agregar el código que tienes realizado, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes importar y usar `colors` con:

```
from core import colors
colors.variable
colors.funcion()
```

O puedes hacerlo así:

```
import core.colors
core.colors.variable
core.colors.funcion()
```

*En ese ultimo caso es aconsejable poner un alias*

Si usas Python 2 te puede dar un error al importar, que puedes solucionar añadiendo en el directorio `core` un archivo `__init__.py` (si no existe ya uno).